# Getting spam Emails after integrated Google reCAPTCHA v2

Tags: typo3, recaptcha

I have implemented reCaptcha in TYPO3 website and after integrated Google reCaptcha V2 api even I am getting spam emails. In reCaptcha admin panel I did not see any erros and warnings messages. I also implemented server side validation and Verifying the user's response.

But I did not understand why I am getting spam emails after integrated reCAPTCHA?

Server side Validation

```
 if(isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty( $_POST['captcha']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
           $captcha=$_POST['captcha'];
         }
         if (empty($_POST['captcha'])) {
           exit('Please set recaptcha variable');
         }
         $secret="************************************";
         $response = $captcha;

         $verify = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secret) .  '&response=' . urlencode($response));
         $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
         if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
           echo '<h2>You are spammer ! This user was not verified by recaptcha.</h2>';
         }
         else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
           echo '<h2>Thanks for posting </h2>';
         }
```

```
{
  "success": true,
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  
  "hostname": string,         
  }
```

Comment: Firstly, have You considered trying recaptcha v3? It is said that v3 is more reliable. Secondly, there are numerous ways how to verify token on server-side and I'm afraid that code sample You posted is not sufficient  in order to resolve Your issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did not consider yet to try reCAPTCHA v3 but may be later on I'll check v3. I want to implemented google reCAPTCHA v2. I have edited server side code.Please have a look.

Comment: Code seems fine to me. About that mail sending, are You using php's mail() function?

Comment: for mail sending I am using formhandler extension in TYPO 3 6.2. This extension is sending an emails.So I did not write any custom code to send an emails  But yes, this extension use php's mail() function to send emails.

Comment: I found several articles at google (and SO as well) on how can be recaptcha bypassed. To sum up, nothing is totally bulletproof, but I would suggest once again trying v3. Have a nice day.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your quick response. Yes I'll check v3 now and you too have a nice day.